# How to set "View all release pipelines" as default view in Release Pipelines

Tags: user-interface, release, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Does anyone know a way to set the "View all release pipelines" as default view for Release Pipelines?
We are using this a lot because it gives a better overview.

[image: Az DevOps UI 'View all release pipelines']

I would expect to find it in the user settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, there is no build-in user settings in Azure DevOps UI to control the default view of release pipeline.

"View active release pipelines" is set as default by design.

[image]

You need to manually switch to "View all release pipelines".

If you would like an option to control the switch this default view, you could create a feature request via: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/AzureDevOps/suggest